# Data formatting/Storing

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Have the following number...

```
0000950123-09-032084
```

It's all numeric, no letters.  I wanted to store it in my database (`sqlite3` for development and `Postgres` for production) using `Activerecord`.

I wanted to setup some type of masking so that I can store the number as `:integer` from a string formated in the above format.

Is there any type of method that can help with this?

I guess I could use...

```
string = "0000950123-09-032084"
number = string.gsub("-","").to_i
```

but I feel there needs to be a better way. Ideal solution would match the pattern and store as integer.

Comment: `string.delete('-').to_i` -- not sure if this is faster, but it does do what you wish

Comment: What form do you want to retrieve it in?

Comment: WHY do you want to store it as an integer? Are you going to do math calculation on it? Add things to it? If not it shouldn't be stored as an integer and should remain as a string. What happens if the number is `0000000000-00-000000`? Do you want to store it as `0`? How do you intend to reconstruct it? These are important question to ask when designing a schema.

Comment: @tinman good points. Not planning to do any math,but thought the formatting should be removed and thought integer fields were more efficient. If they are not, maybe I should keep it a string.

Comment: What is the biggest integer your db can store? Will your string value ever exceed this if converted to an integer?

Comment: @Fred I'm using PG, not sure what the largest integer it can store.  I assume 255 char., but I'll have to research it.

Comment: PG integer = 4 bytes , -2147483648 to +2147483647
bigint= 8 bytes, large-range integer  -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807.  I decided to use a string.  However, would it be advised to remove the formating? e.g. removing "-"?

Comment: Bigint just makes it, but I think your decision is sound. As far as removing the formatting, that depends. How many of these are you expecting to store? How stable is the format (has it ever changed, could a new format make sense, and so forth)? If you don't store a squillion, if you just drop it in as text in some field, storing the format characters might make sense--the tradeoff is storage space against processing time to redo the formatting on output.

Comment: I have about 15-20 million records that need to be processed. They should get processed once and not need to be reprocessed.